# Права на просмотр корневой директории

Tags: linux, permissions

Всем добрый день.

Такой вопрос: почему в линуксах только что созданный юзер по дефолту имеет право на просмотр корневой директории? Видел такое в centos, ubuntu и debian.

Спасибо за ваше время!

Comment: А что скрывать-то? Он не сможет поставить такой же дистр и под рутом посмотреть организацию папок?

Я уж молчу про всякое веселье, когда проверяются права не только на читаемый файл/директорию, но и весь путь от корня.

Comment: Понимаю, но интересно. А про какое веселье именно пишите?

Answer (score 1):

Откройте папку и посмотрите её premission. Смените права пользователей, кроме овна на nothing. [Пикча](http://hkar.ru/v0lF). Для каждой папки есть дефолтные значения, вам их нужно менять под себя для скрытия "важных файлов".